# How to get django user after channels.Demultiplexer?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm trying to build user related websocket service with Django Channels.
I have this Demultiplexer at first line of my routing.py:

```
def checkauth(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):        
        if args[0].message.user.is_anonymous():
            args[0].send(stream="auth", payload = {'m':'pissoff'})
            args[0].close()
            return
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class Demultiplexer(WebsocketDemultiplexer):
    http_user = True

    mapping = {"auth": "user.tracking",}

    @checkauth
    def connect(self, message, **kwargs):

    @checkauth
    def receive(self, content, **kwargs):
```

So, now i writing consumers in routing.py:

```
route('user.tracking', another_app.myconsumer),
```

or

```
route_class(another_app.MyConsumer),`
```

and they hasn't message.user in input.

Do i need call channel_session_user_from_http again?
Is there any reliable way to append user in Demultiplexer?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with accessing user in my consumer function and I ended up decorating it with

```
@channel_session_user
def ws_my_consumer(message):
```

I didn't find a way to do it using my custom Demultiplexer class. I'm not so sure that there exists another solution because even [the documentation](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#websocket-multiplexing) mentions using decorators in the hooked consumers

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 - Get user in Demultiplexer**

```
from channels.generic.websockets import WebsocketDemultiplexer
from foo.consumers import WsFooConsumer

class Demultiplexer(WebsocketDemultiplexer):
    http_user = True

    consumers = {
        "foo": WsFooConsumer,
    }

    def connect(self, content, **kwargs):
        print self.message.user
```

**Option 2 - Get user in JsonWebsocketConsumer subclass**

```
from channels.generic.websockets import WebsocketDemultiplexer
from foo.consumers import WsFooConsumer


class Demultiplexer(WebsocketDemultiplexer):
    consumers = {
        "notifications": WsFooConsumer,
    }
```

**foo.consumers**

```
from channels.generic.websockets import JsonWebsocketConsumer

class WsFooConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    http_user = True

    def connect(self, message, multiplexer, **kwargs):
        print message.user

    def disconnect(self, message, multiplexer, **kwargs):
        print message.user

    def receive(self, content, multiplexer, **kwargs):
        print self.message.user
```